# How to access non-child models from other controller in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, models

I'm having trouble finding information about how to use a model that doesn't belong to the current controller.

For example: I have an ajax controller that sends only JSON data to application.  This controller needs to access different models depending on request.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the Manual section titled [$components, $helpers and $uses](http://book.cakephp.org/view/53/components-helpers-and-uses), you are looking for `$uses`:

```
<?php
class RecipesController extends AppController {
var $name = 'Recipes';
var $uses = array('Recipe', 'User'); // both models will be available
var $helpers = array('Ajax');
var $components = array('Email');
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

$uses causes performance hit. Better way is:

```
$User = ClassRegistry::init('User');
$User->find(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the Recipe and User models are related you could do something like:

```
$this->Recipe->User->find(....);
```